# How to set session value in angular js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

Am beginner in learning angular js,I need to know how to set the session values  like user id, mail,username etc..

kindly tell me the efficient ways to set session values in angular js

thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you provide the code what you've tried?

Answer (score -1):

Reference link [reference link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AngularJS-LocalStorage-and-SessionStorage-example.aspx)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ngstorage/0.3.6/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('MyApp', ["ngStorage"])
        app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorage, $window) {
            $scope.Save = function () {
                $localStorage.LocalMessage = "LocalStorage: My name is Mudassar Khan.";
                $sessionStorage.SessionMessage = "SessionStorage: My name is Mudassar Khan.";
            }
            $scope.Get = function () {
                $window.alert($localStorage.LocalMessage + "\n" + $sessionStorage.SessionMessage);
            }
        });
    </script>
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="Save()" />
        <input type="button" value="Get" ng-click="Get()" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```